# Call a listener method from a worker thread but have it run on the thread that added the listener

Tags: java, multithreading, listeners

I'm writing a TCP server class that I want to be self-contained.  That is, the applications that use this class need not worry about the internal worker threads.  The TCP server class has a start() method and I want to be able to call the listener's methods on the same thread that called start() (under normal use, the main thread).  This is probably better explained with code:

```java
public class ProblemExample {
    private Listener mListener;

    public ProblemExample() {
        mListener = new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void fireListener() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        };
    }

    public void start() {
        mListener.fireListener(); // "main" is printed
        new Thread(new Worker()).start();
    }

    public interface Listener {
        public void fireListener();
    }

    private class Worker implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Assuming the listener is being used for status updates while
             * the thread is running, I'd like to fire the listener on the
             * same thread that called start(). Essentially, the thread that
             * starts the operation doesn't need to know or care about the
             * internal thread. */
            mListener.fireListener(); // "Thread-0" is printed
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for this but I'm not really sure what to search for.  The best I've found is that [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) seems to do this, but I can't find out how.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: How is it possible? Assume a corner case, e.g. that the starter thread was terminated. How is it possible to tell from one thread what another should do? Consider using a queue or the ExecutorService. BTW, your question doesn't tell anything about the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is theoretically impossible without explicit cooperation from the client thread (the one that called `start()`). Just stop to think about it: the main thread is always busy running some specific code, in some specific method. The complete call stack is dedicated to the current call. Now you would like to interrupt that and start executing listener code out of the blue.

The way Swing achieves this is by running a main event loop in the Event Dispatch Thread. In this loop, you can imagine instances of `Runnable` being pulled off of a queue and their `run` methods called in turn. Only when one `run` method returns can the next one be called.

This is what you need to design for your case as well, but I'm not sure whether you had something like that in mind. The only alternative is explicit support for listener methods being executed on a foreign thread.

Comment: Ok thanks, and thanks kan.  Since I intend for this TCP server to be re-used, I had thought it would be better designed that it didn't allow listeners to block the worker thread and it would also play nicer with Swing apps if the listeners were updating a UI.

So, is it best practise to just call the listener from the worker thread and leave it at that?

Comment: If your goal is for the listeners to be invoked in the Swing EDT, then just have the worker thread use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() when you want to call the listeners. That won't block the worker threads, and the listeners will be called in the EDT. But to be able to do that with any kind of thread, then you need the thread's collaboration.

Comment: Just recently I've done a project where I could compare the work queue and `synchronized` approaches side-by-side and the `synchronized` approach's advantage is that it composes better due to re-entrancy of locks. It is also easier to implement: just use the `synchronized` keyword. Swing, on the other hand, is better off with a work queue due to the fine granularity of actions. So there is no single best practice: know the ups and downs of both approaches and deploy the best fit.